generating random numbers with numpy using multiprocessing
I want to generate random numbers in Numpy using Multiprocessing. Using this this answer I wrote the code at the end of this message, and it seems to work. Because answer I linked to is quite old, I want to make sure that it is still correct. Numpy's official documentation seems to say that np.random.seed is deprecated, but I can't seem to find good documentation about the Generator instance it recommends, and it seems more complicated.
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool

def generate_random(iproc):
    # if then next line is commented then each process produces same random numbers
    np.random.seed()
    nums = np.random.uniform(size=8)
    print(f'{iproc=},{nums=}')
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nproc = 8
    arglist = []
    for iproc in range(nproc):
        arglist.append((iproc,))
        
    with Pool(nproc) as p:
        p.starmap(generate_random, arglist)


There's nothing wrong with the old generator; it just isn't going to get further developments. Saying its convenience, legacy function is not the same as deprecated.

You can create a new generator generator = numpy.random.default_rng(seed=None) then you can use it like numpy.random. It is a way to avoid global state where you get unexpected results. Such as what you're experiencing. When you don't use numpy.random.seed the global state is starts the same for all of the subprocesses.

Note this will not be very efficient. Multiprocessing has a huge overhead when it comes to sharing data with sub-processes. Pickling array, sending them using IPC and unpickling them. While you can make it a bit faster, the operation will quickly get memory bound and the amount of work much bigger than what is actually useful (so the scalability on few core should be small and the same for many cores). Using shared array should help though but it is more complex (much more than just using a native language for that and things like OpenMP which is also more efficient for this)

To avoid sharing a global random state object you could seed the subprocesses with different seeds. Here is a minimal example of how to achieve this with Numpy's generator API:
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool


def generate_random(idx_proc, seed):
    random_state = np.random.RandomState(seed)
    nums = random_state.uniform(size=8)
    print(f"{idx_proc=}, {nums=}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    n_proc = 8

    random_state = np.random.RandomState(480273)

    seeds = random_state.randint(0, 2**32-1, n_proc)

    with Pool(n_proc) as p:
        p.starmap(generate_random, enumerate(seeds))

By using a random state object in the main process and generating the seeds from it you will get reproducible results (however keep in mind that the order the processes run in and compute the numbers might not be reproducible!).
I hope this helps!
